# Lambda print IP return null

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm pretty new and unexperienced with Python but I want to create a lambda function that creates and prints the public IP
So far I got this code but the response is still null and I don't know why.

```
import json
import os
import boto3
import time

AMI = os.environ['AMI']
INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['INSTANCE_TYPE']
KEY_NAME = os.environ['KEY_NAME']
SUBNET_ID = os.environ['SUBNET_ID']

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    
        instance = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        )
        time.sleep(5)
        print (instance[0].public_ip_address)
```

Comment: When you say the response is null, do you mean that the return value from the lambda_handler function is None, or that it's printing None?

Comment: Also, rather than wait some arbitrary amount of time, be aware of [boto3 EC2 waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#waiters). That said, waiting in a Lambda function is not an ideal practice, so if you can avoid doing it, you should.

Comment: You aren't returning anything, so the response will be empty. All you are doing is printing something to the Lambda function's logs right now. Also, I don't think there is any guarantee the IP will be available in 5 seconds.